# Days are not added properly with momentJS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have this code where I want to get next 15 days from the start date

```
    var fortnightStart = moment("15 04 2015", "DD MM YYYY");

    for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {

        dates.push(fortnightStart.add(i, "days").format("D MMM"));

    }

    console.log(dates);
```

This is the output

```
["16 Apr", "18 Apr", "21 Apr", "25 Apr", "30 Apr", "6 May", "13 May", "21 May", "30 May", "9 Jun", "20 Jun", "2 Jul", "15 Jul", "29 Jul", "13 Aug"]
```

I don't know why its missing a few days.

Comment: The `.add()` function **modifies** the moment (date) object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On every iteration you add `i` days to your initial date - so it keeps accumulating (+1, +2, +3 etc). You need to add not `i` but simply `1` to `fortnightStart`.

```
var fortnightStart = moment("15 04 2015", "DD MM YYYY");
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    // 1, not i
    dates.push(fortnightStart.add(1, "days").format("D MMM"));
}
console.log(dates);
```

Comment: This works, but as other people have pointed, out, you need to know that `.add()` is mutating the base date. The only reason this loop works is that you're pushing a formatted string into the dates array, not an actual moment. If you were to drop the `.format()` out, you'd end up with an array of many references to the same moment.

Comment: @SMcCrohan totally agree with you. Another option is to create new date object or clone `fortnightStart` before adding days.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `.add` modifies the object passed in instead of creating a new date. To keep your code in its original style, you need to [clone the date](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) before adding to it.

```
dates.push(fortnightStart.clone().add(i, "days").format("D MMM"));
```

Or:

```
dates.push(moment(fortnightStart).add(i, "days").format("D MMM"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're missing dates is because 'date.add' changes the current variable. E.g.

```
date = moment("15 04 2015", "DD MM YYYY");
date.add(1, "days");
console.log(date); // This will give you "16 04 2015"
```

For your code to work correctly, you need to make sure that either:

1) The 'add' method doesn't change your original value by adding to a clone. e.g.

```
dates.push(fortnightStart.clone().add(i, "days").format("D MMM"));
```

OR

2) You only add 1 day every loop instead if 'i' days. e.g.

```
dates.push(fortnightStart.clone().add(1, "days").format("D MMM"));
```